# vc142 and 2019 redistributable package comparison with vc141

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there a reason (I guess yes but I try to discover it) to install 2019 redistributable when deploying a C++ application built with *vc142* since applications seems to work perfectly with the previous redistributable  package (coming with vc141)? I have in mind that both are binary compatible, but more than that, `dumpbin /exports` of *msvcp140.dll* and *vcruntime140.dll* from 2017 and 2019 redistributable produce the same output; file size are identical too.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried a bindiff?

Comment: Aparrently they are binary compatible: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp-binary-compatibility-and-pain-free-upgrades-to-visual-studio-2019/

Comment: @Ben I have tried on vcruntime140.dll  and msvcp140.dll  with dumpbin.exe / exports and a tool for comparing difference in output and they are the same

Comment: I believe the compatibility promise is that libraries compiled agaisnt vc140 and vc141 will work at runtime with the vc142 library, not necessarily the other way round. If that's right you should ship the latest version.

Comment: dumpbin shows the exported function names. Bindiff will show you if the implementation is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is no gotcha, the libraries are comptible, see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019

The article states: "This reflects the fact that both the runtime libraries and the applications compiled with either version of the compiler are binary compatible."

Maybe there are performance related differences.

As vs 2019 supports later c++ standard than 2017, this leaves one to wonder how this is possible with the old runtime libraries. I guess the differences are all built into the main executable/dll and don't require any changes in the runtime dlls.